# How to solve the following problem related to degree $5$ polynomial.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ and $$\alpha=\sum_{i=0}^6P(x_i)\bigg(\prod_{j=0, j\neq i}^6(x_i-x_j)^{-1}\bigg),$$
where $x_0, x_1, \ldots , x_6$ are distinct points in the interval $[2, 3]$, then show that
$\alpha^2  -\alpha =0$.

I am not able to start this problem. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: In terms of divided differences, $α=P[x_1,x_2,...,x_6]=P^{(5)}(ξ)/5!$ is the degree-5 leading coefficient of the polynomial. The claim is only true if $P$ is additionally a monic polynomial, that is, with leading coefficient $1$, of degree 5 or lower. Otherwise the claim is wrong.